# Reload JavaScript files in Angular 6 on every page load

Tags: javascript, reload, angular6, pageload

I made some javascripts files for animation. Which I want to reload on every page load. How can I do it?

Comment: init the function call ngOnInit()

Comment: You want to reload the files? Just call again the functions in them...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: As per my basic knowledge in Angular, angular load the JavaScript files once on project execution. But in my case I want to reload the JavaScript functions on every page load. I can call at OnInit but I don't know how to call JavaScript or JavaScript functions from angular 6

Comment: Then your question is "how do I call JavaScript from TypeScript"

Answer (score 0):

```
reloadJSFile() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'myscripts.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  success: 'myfunction()'
});
```

create a service and on every ngOnInit. that it.